# What causes buildings to collapse in Battlebit Remastered?

Tags: battlebit-remastered

Occasionally while playing Battlebit Remastered, buildings will collapse converting from a 1 or more story building into a ruins/rubble pile. This usually happens during extended firefights where there is a lot of RPG or Tank fire into the building. However it feels really random *when* the buildings collapse. Sometimes a building can be taking RPG fire for a long time and nothing really happens other than some walls being destroyed, other times that same building starts rumbling and collapses early in the fight.

It would be useful to know exactly what triggers the collapse, so that me or my squad could bring down certain buildings on purpose to make attacking or defending certain points easier.

**In Battlebit Remastered what causes the destructible buildings to collapse?**

Is there a total health pool of the building that needs to be reduced, specific destructible walls that need to be removed, a percentage of *any* destructible walls that need to be removed, or something else?